# not able to change a value assigned to this object using .bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, bind

I'm using angular to develop a web app and I'm trying to use a function's `.bind` method to assign the this value on a method of one of my controllers.  It looks like this:

```
var welcomeCtrl = function (userManager) {
  this.partnerName = userManager.getName('partner');
  this.yourName = userManager.getName('you');
  this.beginScan = false;
  var self = this;
};

welcomeCtrl.prototype.scanThumb = function (callback) {
  function doScan() {
    alert(this);
    alert(this.beginScan);
    this.finishedScanning = callback;
    this.beginScan = true;
  }

  doScan.bind(welcomeCtrl)();

};
```

So what happens is that a directive passes the scanThumb method to a service which executes it, which should then trigger another directive waiting for `this.beginScan` to be true.

Since its the service that calls the method and it is not called from the `welcomCtrl` class, I need to bind `this` back to `welcomeCtrl` so I use `.bind` and pass in `welcomeCtrl`

This should work, when I do `alert(this)` the welcomeCtrl function definition alerts fine, but when I do `alert(this.beginScan)` I get `Undefined`

Am I not understanding how the .bind method works in this circumstance?

Comment: Aren't you just passing in the constructor for your `welcomeCtrl` object? Should just do `doScan.bind(this)();` to reference your current object instance.

Comment: I didn't even think about that but you're right I'm passing the uninitiated constructor so that's likely the problem.  now as for passing in `this` won't that bind doScan to whatever `this` currently refers to? Which in my case is not what it needs to be

Comment: In the situation of being inside `welcomeCtrl.prototype.scanThumb`, `this` should simply be your current instance of `welcomeCtrl`, which is what you're trying to modify inside the `doScan` function.

Comment: I did get it working not exactly in the way you suggested but I did get it working thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jesse Kernaghan suggested I was simply was passing the uninitiated constructor as the the thisParam. I fixed this by modifying my service to take 2 parameters, a callback, and a thisParam. I had then had to pass in the `scope` as the thisParam from my directive, and in my service call the callback with a `.bind(thisParam)` and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using an object's inner function (in this case, `welcomeCtrl`) `this` refers to the current object.

Take the following example:

```
var Foo = function(){
  this.thing = 'bar';
}

Foo.prototype.setThing = function(newthing){
  //our inner function
  function doInnerThing(){
    //this is now bound to our current Foo instance
    console.log(this);
    //setting our current Foo.thing to new value
    this.thing = newthing;  
  };
  //fire function, bound to current object scope (Foo)
  doInnerThing.bind(this)();
};

Foo.prototype.doThing = function(){
  alert(this.thing);
};

var newFoo = new Foo();
var newFoo2 = new Foo();

newFoo.setThing('newFoo');
newFoo.doThing(); //alerts 'newFoo', the overridden value


newFoo2.doThing();//alerts 'bar', the base value
```

Comment: I agree that's how it works, however that's not what I'm doing. I'm passing a method of a class to another function as a callback.  The other function calls that method meaning that `this` now refers to the other function, not the function which constructed the method

Comment: From your original question, I gathered the callback should be getting passed into the inner function and bound to  `welcomeCtrl.finishedScanning`. Is that not what you're hoping to achieve? If not, where is the object/context you want the inner function bound to?

Comment: If you're familiar with angularJS I described that I'm using a directive to call a service to call a method on the controller.  the method is bound to the scope of the directive through a custom html attribute, the directive calls a service and passes that method to it so that when the service is done it uses that method as a callback.